# I can nt make a sum in a nested mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried all weekend to write this query, but it is not working. The nested field worked, but the other field does not show the $sum.

This is a example of the collections:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5dc28a3fd89a4d7bb82a75b4"),
  "bedrijf": ObjectId("5c7ee51d2478a30fa4357b4c"),
  "doelgroep": "Kinderen 12-",
  "recreatieleider": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
```

I like to group the key "bedrijf" and make a subgroup "doelgroep" The code I use is:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      bedrijf: "$bedrijf",
      doelgroep: "$doelgroep",
    },
    "totaal": {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
},
{
  $group : {
    _id : '$_id.bedrijf',
    doelgroep : {
      "$push": {
        doelgroep:"$_id.doelgroep",
        total:"$totaal"
      }
  },
    "recreatieleider": {
      $sum: "$recreatieleider"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I see the results the key "recreatieleder" does not make the sum of the entries.

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "_id": "5c69c5d939fbb38a1fcf3146",
        "doelgroep": [
            {
                "doelgroep": "Gezinnen",
                "total": 1
            },
            {
                "doelgroep": "Kinderen 9-11",
                "total": 9
            }
        ],
        "recreatieleider": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

So how can I count the "recreatieleider" value?

My final expected output must be:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "_id": "5c69c5d939fbb38a1fcf3146",
        "doelgroep": [
            {
                "doelgroep": "Gezinnen",
                "total": 1
            },
            {
                "doelgroep": "Kinderen 9-11",
                "total": 9
            }
        ],
        "recreatieleider": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

### *added question*

I ran to a other problem. You make me fixed the first problem. When a mak a other sub group it will not show me

I use this code

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      bedrijf: "$bedrijf",
      doelgroep: "$doelgroep",
    },
    "totaal": {
      $sum: 1
    },
    "hulpkrachten": {
      $sum: "$hulpkrachten"
    },
    "recreatieleider": {
      $sum: "$recreatieleider"
    },
    "stagiaires": {
      $sum: "$stagiaires"
    },
  }
},
{
  $group : {
    _id : '$_id.bedrijf',
    doelgroep : {
      "$push": {
        doelgroep:"$_id.doelgroep",
        total:"$totaal"
      }
  },
  soortactiviteit : {
    "$push": {
      soortactiviteit:"$_id.soortactiviteit",
      total:"$totaal"
    }
}
  }
}
```

You can see I add "soortactiviteit" to it, but it wil not add u subgroup

The expeditor outcome must be

```
    {
"results": [
    {
        "_id": "5c69c5d939fbb38a1fcf3146",
        "doelgroep": [
            {
                "doelgroep": "Gezinnen",
                "total": 1
            },
            {
                "doelgroep": "Kinderen 9-11",
                "total": 9
            }
        ],
            "soortactivieit": [
            {
                "doelgroep": "creativiteit",
                "total": 20
            },
            {
                "doelgroep": "sports,
                "total": 9
            }
        ],
        "recreatieleider": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Maybe you can help with my last question of the subject.. Thank

Comment: show us your final expected output

Comment: The expected output must contain ... "recreatieleider": 20 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, what you are trying to achieve with this query. However, below query works for your scenario.

```
{ 
   $group:{ 
      _id:{ 
         bedrijf:"$bedrijf",
         doelgroep:"$doelgroep",

      },
      "totaal":{ 
         $sum:1
      },
      "recreatieleider":{ 
         $sum:"$recreatieleider"
      }
   }
},
{ 
   $group:{ 
      _id:'$_id.bedrijf',
      doelgroep:{ 
         "$push":{ 
            doelgroep:"$_id.doelgroep",
            total:"$totaal"
         }
      },
      "recreatieleider":{ 
         $sum:"$recreatieleider"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When first $group runs the key recreatieleider is lost in

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      bedrijf: "$bedrijf",
      doelgroep: "$doelgroep",
    },
    "totaal": {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
},
```

change it to and try then:

```
{
      $group: {
        _id: {
          bedrijf: "$bedrijf",
          doelgroep: "$doelgroep",
        },
        "totaal": {
          $sum: 1
        },
        "recreatieleider": {
          $sum: "$recreatieleider"
        }
      }
    },
```